# Why does AOSP Marshmallow reboot when a location API is triggered?

Tags: android-source, android-6.0-marshmallow

I built AOSP from source (Marshmallow), for my Nexus 5. Everything seems to work, except that if ANY app tries to use the location, it causes the device to reboot.

When building from source, is one expected to implement a driver or something for the GPS ?

Comment: One is just about always expected to implement or else provide a vendors GPS driver, if one expect that functionality to work, yes.  Debugging your particular issue should probably start with figuring out if you are experiencing an actual kernel reboot, or just an Android runtime restart, then proceed to understanding why.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But Google provides all the proprietary blobs - Aren't the proprietary blobs the actual drivers ? I extracted them according to the instructions, and the camera works, and I can make phone calls.... Is there really no GPS driver ?